# Creating a line graph in excel with changing/result cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, charts

For a project we are creating care packages for the homeless. I am trying to figure how many kits to make for the least leftover material as the things we are putting into the packages are sold in different units/case. I have every item filled into a sheet in excel with formulas that take the changing value, the number of kits, and runs through a bunch of calculations in multiple different cells, eventually ending up in the result cell, the cost, rounded to the nearest case. Photo for clarity:

[image]

B1 is my changing cell and B4 is my result.

Now my problem arises when I want to create a line chart that shows the cost to make different number of kits. I would like the X axis to be 50-200 and the Y axis to be the theoretical cost(cost per kit * number of kits) and the real subtotal(cost per kit to the nearest case of each item). Could I do this? and how?

I don't have one singular formula to calculate the real subtotal as there are so many different items coming in different cases and prices.

Comment: You chart data rather than a formula.  You would need to build a table of the X and Y values (derived from your existing formulas), and then chart the result.

Comment: As fixer1234 wrote, you need a table to be able to plot the chart. Are only the highlighted cells calculated in your sheet. Most important: is "units per kit" fixed across scenarios?

Comment: Everything that is highlighted in yellow is calculated. "Units per kits" is fixed across scenarios. In fact, the only thing I am changing is the number of kits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To chart real vs theoretical cost, first you need to calculate them against the number of kits:

[image]

Formulas:

- Theoretical cost: `=A21*SUMPRODUCT($E$6:$E$16,$D$6:$D$16)`
- Real subtotal: `=SUMPRODUCT(ROUNDUP(A21*$E$6:$E$16/$C$6:$C$16,0),$B$6:$B$16)` - this is an array formula, so you need to finish it by CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER
- I've included also a "real / theoretical" cost column, which just divide real subtotal by theoretical cost, so it gives you also the information how much "extra" you spend over real value of the kits
- NOTE: input range is the same as posted in the question

Chart:

- instead of a single chart, I suggest to use [pivot chart](https://support.office.com/en-us/Article/Create-a-PivotChart-c1b1e057-6990-4c38-b52b-8255538e7b1c), this enable also filtering of input data (zoom to specific range to see costs better)